# Not getting any response for save

Tags: express, mongoose

Whenever I request on `8081/list_user` there is no response. When I open `localhost:8081` I get a response but not for `localhost:8081/list_user`.Both files are in the same folder is there any issues with that.Please check this issue what's problem in that.

```
    // grab the things we need schema.js file
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    // create a schema
    var userSchema = new Schema({
      name: String,
    });

    // the schema is useless so far
    // we need to create a model using it
    var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

    // make this available to our users in our Node applications
    console.log("Schema")
    module.exports = User;


    ////////////Next file
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var User = require('./schema');

    // This responds with "Hello World" on the homepage
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
       console.log("Got a GET request for the homepage",User);
       res.send('Hello GET');
    })

    // This responds a POST request for the homepage
    app.post('/', function (req, res) {
       console.log("Got a POST request for the homepage");
       res.send('Hello POST');
    })

    // This responds a DELETE request for the /del_user page.
    app.delete('/del_user', function (req, res) {
       console.log("Got a DELETE request for /del_user");
       res.send('Hello DELETE');
    })

    // This responds a GET request for the /list_user page.
    app.get('/list_user', function (req, res) {
       console.log("Got a GET request for /list_user");
      var newUser = User({
      name: 'Peter Quill',

      });

    // save the user
    newUser.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    res.send('User created!');
      console.log('User created!');

    });


    })

    // This responds a GET request for abcd, abxcd, ab123cd, and so on
    app.get('/find', function(req, res) {   
       User.find({}, function(err, users) {
      if (err) throw err;

      // object of all the users
      console.log(users);
    res.send(users)

    });

    })

    var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

       var host = server.address().address
       var port = server.address().port

       console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tested .save function the way it was I couldn't even get an error message. What I did was add a connection with my local database (at schema file) to test properly.

> mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

In order to do this, first you have to certify that you have a local mongodb server running (or you could just connect to an online server), mongoose.connect receives my connection string as parameter ("test" is the database name, if it doesn't exist it will be created automatically). Last thing I did was add **new** when I create an user.

```
var newUser = new User({
    name: 'teste',
});
```

Comment: Above 11 lines are of schema file.

Comment: @SaurabhJoshi I just updated my answer, please check it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot..mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test'); was the issue.

Comment: @SaurabhJoshi I'm glad that I could help! Please mark it as correct the answer.